# Pass several files to another app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fileprovider

I'm creating a file-chooser and I'm passing a file through `Intent` like this:

```
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity, FILE_PROVIDER_ID, file);
Intent sIntent = new Intent("ACTION_RETURN_FILE").setData(uri);
activity.setResult(RESULT_OK, sIntent);
```

It works. But now I need to pass a couple of file through `Intent`. At first, I tried to call `intent.setData` twice, but it doesn't seem to work, because

> This method automatically clears any type that was previously set.

It there a way to pass a few files to an another app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's achievable with [`Intent#setClipData(ClipData)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClipData(android.content.ClipData)) API.

You can see example usage from [Ian Lake](https://twitter.com/ianhlake)'s talk [*"Forget the Storage Permission: Alternatives for sharing and collaborating"*](https://youtu.be/C28pvd2plBA?t=1579) talk at Big Android BBQ.

[image]
<sup>A slide from the abovementioned talk.</sup>

An example usage:

```
// Adding into `Intent`
ClipData clipData = ClipData.newRawUri(null, contentUri);
clipData.addItem(new ClipData.Item(secondContentUri));
intent.setClipData(clipData);

// Retrieving from `Intent`
ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
for (int i = 0, count = clipData.getItemCount(); i < count; ++i) {
    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
    Uri uri = item.getUri();
}
```

Comment: As I understood the another app should support clipData?
I need to create a file-provider for standard app such as email client.